# Cannot update Offset using JQuery in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to set an the offset of an element.
The code works ok in Chrome but i can't get the offset to change in IE;

```
this.moveH = function (e) {

    if (this.target != null){
        console.log(this.target.offset())
        this.target.offset({
            left: e.pageX - this.target.outerWidth(true) / 2,
            top: e.pageY - this.target.outerHeight(true) / 2
        });
    }
    console.log(this.target.offset())
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

If i run in chrome the first console.log is different from the second. If i run in IE it never changes.
Thank you

**Update 1**
The offset function is the one from JQuery

**Update 2** Added HTML and CSS

```
*{
    margin:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
}
#applet {
    position: absolute;
    width: 700px;
    height: 520px;
    direction:ltr;
    text-align: center;
}
#puzzle{
    top:80px;
    left:20px;
    position:absolute;
}

.left-column{
    position:absolute;
    width:388px;
}

.left-puzzle{
    margin-top:10px;
    width:388px;
    background-image:url("../images/left_puzzle.png");
    height:83px;
}
.left-puzzle p{
    margin-right:194px;
}

.right-column{
    float:right;
    left:500px;
    width:182px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.targets{
    left:206px;
    top:1px;
    width:194px;
    position:absolute;
}
.target{
    margin-top:10px;
    width:194px;
    height:83px;
}
.right-puzzle{
    margin-top:10px;
    width:182px;
    height:82px;
    background-image:url("../images/right_puzzle.png")
}

#bg{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id='applet'>
            <img id='bg' src='images/background.jpg' />
            <div id="puzzle">

                <div class="left-column">

                    <div class="left-puzzle">
                        <p>يبدأ خلف الشرج ولدى بعض الحبليات ذيل يوجد في مرحلة الجنين فقط.</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="left-puzzle">
                        <p>يمتد بطول الظهر وهو مليء بالسائل عند الفقاريات ويطلق عليه اسم الحبل الشوكي .</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="left-puzzle">
                        <p>تتطور إلى خياشيم أو إلى أجزاء أخرى من الجسم أثناء تطور الجنين .</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="left-puzzle">
                        <p>قضيب صلب لكنه مرن يدعم الجسم وفي الفقاريات يحل محله عمود فقري .</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="targets">
                    <div class="target drop" id="t1"></div>
                    <div class="target drop" id="t2"></div>
                    <div class="target drop" id="t3"></div>
                    <div class="target drop" id="t4"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="right-column">
                    <div id="d1" class="right-puzzle drag" data-target-id="t2">
                        <p>الحبل العصبي المجوف</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="d2" class="right-puzzle drag" data-target-id="t1">
                        <p>الذيل</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="d3" class="right-puzzle drag" data-target-id="t3">
                        <p>الجيوب البلعومية </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="d4" class="right-puzzle drag" data-target-id="t4">
                        <p>الحبل الظهري</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: how is the function offset() defined?

Comment: my fault it's the JQuery Offset function

Comment: Did you try to use the dev tool and go step by step to see where things went wrong?

Comment: @Huangism i get no errors every thing seams ok, when logging the offset in IE it remanins unchanged, but it works in Chrome, Firefox and Safari

Comment: if you use the dev tool, assuming you are on a desktop, you can set breakpoints in js and see each step of the code as the browser executes them. If you are not on desktop then it could have something to do with zoom. A quick google search will bring up some decent results for ie10 offset issue when zoomed

Comment: @Huangism i know excatly were the problem, it's in the offset function when i log the value after it's supposed to be updated it's still the same

Comment: Yea but does e.pageX - this.target.outerWidth(true) / 2 and other calculation return a different number than expected?

Comment: Yes it does i already tested it.

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference, but you can always set top then left :) maybe it's a glitch. If you set up a fiddle, I will try to find an IE10 machine to test it

Answer (score 0):

Try using native javascript instead.
Use obj.offsetLeft and obj.offsetTop. It should work in IE as well. Looks like a cross browser issue to me.